# Accessing MySQL database in d3.js with php file

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, d3.js, undefined

I need some help with MySQL and D3 with a php file.

I am trying to get access to my database using D3. I have created a php file where I make the connection to MySQL.

My problem is however that I get an empty array when printing out my output to the console from D3. I can't seem to find what I am doing wrong. Below is my code for both the D3 call and the php file: (I have appropriate names from username, password and database name.)

```
<?php
    $host = "localhost";
    $port = 8889;
    $username = "********"; 
    $password = "********";   
    $database="***datebasename***";
    if (!$server) {
        die('Not connected : ' .mysql_error());
    }
    $server = mysql_connect($host, $user, $password);

    $connection = mysql_select_db($database, $server);

    if (isset($_GET['type'])) {
        $type = $_GET['type'];
    } else {
        $type = "null";
        echo "Type not passed";
    }

    if($type=='load'){
        $string = '';
        $gene = $_GET["gene"];
        $data = $_GET["data"];

        $myquery = "select gene_data.gene_data from genes inner join gene_data on genes.id=gene_data.g_id where genes.name ='$gene' and genes.type='$data'";
        $query = mysql_query($myquery);

        if ( !$myquery || !$query) {
            echo mysql_error();
            die;
        }

        $data = array();
        for ($x = 0; $x < mysql_num_rows($query); $x++) {
            $data[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
        }

        echo json_encode($data);
        mysql_close($server);
    }
?>
```

My file are all running from a server. The MySQL server is also on the same server, so I jut call localhost to get access. Also since I need several different parameters for my SQL calls I send the values from D3 ("gene" and "human").

The following the call I make from D3:

```
d3.json("getdata.php?type=load&gene=CLL5&data=human", function(error, data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Also it is worth mentioning that my query is tested and works.

Some help would be greatly appreciated!  Any ideas on how to debug with and prints or write.outs would be appretiated as well!

Comment: Does `error` contain anything?

Comment: No, I don't get any errors. I get an empty array. I suspect it has something to do with how D3 interprets the data from the result i echo from the php file?

Comment: Can you post an example of what JSON the call returns?

Comment: The Json call actually returns this now after I've been fiddeling with it for a while: SyntaxError {stack: (...), message: "Unexpected token N"}

This is from the very first if-statement from my php file I think. Because if I remove it I get another error: SyntaxError {stack: (...), message: "Unexpected token A"}.

this comes from this if-statement:if ( !$myquery || !$query) {
            echo mysql_error();
            die;
        }